# Spring WS and MessageDispatcherServlet: How to define the exact URL for a WSDL?

Tags: java, servlets, wsdl, spring-ws

I'm running a standalone application (no web app container) with

- Spring 3.2.4
- Spring-WS 2.1.4
- Jetty 8.1.13 (Embedded Jetty)

I've set up Jetty embedded with a servlet context like this:

```
<bean id="servletContext" class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
  <property name="contextPath" value="/" />
  <property name="servletHandler">
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
      <property name="servlets">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder" p:name="dispatcherServlet" p:servlet-ref="dispatcherServlet" />
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder" p:name="messageDispatcherServlet" p:servlet-ref="messageDispatcherServlet" />
        </list>
      </property>
      <property name="servletMappings">
        <list>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping" p:pathSpec="/services" p:servletName="dispatcherServlet" />
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping" p:pathSpec="/ws/*" p:servletName="messageDispatcherServlet" />
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dispatcherServlet" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet">
  <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext">
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/dispatcherServlet-context.xml" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="messageDispatcherServlet" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext">
            <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/messageDispatcherServlet-context.xml" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

As you can see, there are 2 servlets defined, the first is a

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

and the second is a

```
org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet
```

Those have two seperate spring context config xml files (XmlWebApplicationContext):

**dispatcherServlet-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  [... xmlns etc. here ...]
  >

  <bean name="/test" class="com.mycompany.TestHttpRequestHandler" />

</beans>
```

**messageDispatcherServlet-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  [... xmlns etc. here ...]
  >

  <bean class="com.mycompany.TestWebServiceEndpoint" />

  <bean name="TestWebService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.SimpleWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="wsdl">
      <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
        <constructor-arg>
          <value>classpath:/TestWebServiceEndpoint.wsdl</value>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

Everything works fine - I can call the "TestHttpRequestHandler" (DispatcherServlet) under the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8181/services/test
```

And I can call the WSDL under the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8181/ws/TestWebService.wsdl
```

**But (!)** - and this is my problem - I can also use the URL

```
http://localhost:8181/ws/bar/TestWebService.wsdl
```

or

```
http://localhost:8181/ws/bat/foo/TestWebService.wsdl
```

or

```
http://localhost:8181/ws/bat/foo/whatever/TestWebService.wsdl
```

and everytime the browser shows the WSDL XML code of the "TestWebService".

My expectation was, that the URL is mapped by the bean name, like in the example with the

```
<bean name="/test" class="com.mycompany.TestHttpRequestHandler" />
```

where this gets mapped to `http://localhost:8181/services/test`.

But it seems for the "MessageDispatcherServlet", this does not work. It just recognizes any WSDL beans in it's context and returns it, whatever URL the user calls (just the name of the WSDL file must match).

Long explanation but short question:

**How can I specify the exact (and only valid) URL for the "TestWebService.wsdl" when using the MessageDispatcherServlet?**

Thanks a lot for your help!